# How to add a second class in JavaScript with the same properties as another class?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have tried a lot to add another class that works in JavaScript with the same properties as another class in the same script. But all my attempts failed. Could you help me to do that?

```js
// FORM
let currentSlide = 0;
let slide = document.querySelectorAll('.form__slide');
let steps = document.querySelectorAll(".form__step--number");
const showSlide = (n) => {
  slide[n].style.display = "block";

  //Button hidding
  if (n == 0) {
    document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "none";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "inline";
  }
  if (n == (slide.length - 1)) {
    document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Submit";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Next"; 
  }

  //Progress Bar
  //let steps = document.querySelectorAll(".form__step--number");

  for(let m = 0; m <=n; m++) {
    steps[m].style.backgroundColor = "var(--green)";
    steps[m].style.color = "var(--white)";
  }
}


const nextPrev = (n) => { 
  
  //Validate Form
  console.log(validateForm());
  if (n == 1 && !validateForm()) return false; 
  
  //Hiding the current Slide
  slide[currentSlide].style.display = null;
  if(n == -1) {
    steps[currentSlide].style.backgroundColor = "var(--white)";
    steps[currentSlide].style.color = "var(--green)";
  }

  //Implement prev and next logic
  currentSlide = currentSlide + n;
  if (currentSlide >= slide.length) { 
    //...the form gets submitted:
    document.querySelector(".form").submit();
    alert("Confirm form Submission");   
    return false;
  }
  showSlide(currentSlide);

  

}

const validateForm = () => {
  const childInput = slide[currentSlide].querySelectorAll('.form__input');
  const arrayInput = Array.prototype.slice.call(childInput);
  let valid = true;
  arrayInput.map((input) => {
  valid = input.checkValidity();
  });
  return valid;
  //console.log(valid);

  // const input = document.querySelectorAll('.form__input');
  // const arr = Array.prototype.slice.call(input)
  // const zz = arr.filter((x)=> {
  //   return x.style.display = "block"; 
  // });
  // console.log(zz);
}

showSlide(currentSlide); 

console.log(slide[0].querySelectorAll('.form__input'));
```

```css
:root {
  --black: #000000;
  --white: #ffffff;
  --cream: #f3efe9;
  --textColor: #181818;
  --red: #EE4957;
  --orange: #ff8552;
  --green: #01B262;
  --gree: #6DBC70;
  --lightGrey: #e6e6e6;
  --darkGrey: #33312e;
  --lightBlue: #25a6e7; }

*,
*::after,
*::before {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: inherit; }

html {
  font-size: 62.5%; }
  @media (max-width: 1080px) {
    html {
      font-size: 60%; } }
  @media (max-width: 900px) {
    html {
      font-size: 56%; } }
  @media (max-width: 768px) {
    html {
      font-size: 50%; } }
  @media (max-width: 600px) {
    html {
      font-size: 43%; } }

body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Montserrat',sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  background-color: var(--cream);
  color: var(--textColor); }

.heading {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2.2rem;
  padding: .3rem; }

.secondary-heading {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  font-weight: 300; }

.form-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center; }

.form {
  width: 80%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center; }
  .form__title {
    font-weight: 600;
    margin: 1rem auto;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 2.5rem; }
  .form__progress-bar {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    position: relative;
    margin: 4rem 0rem; }
    .form__progress-bar::before {
      content: " ";
      position: absolute;
      top: 24%;
      left: 5%;
      display: block;
      background-color: var(--green);
      width: 90%;
      min-height: .3rem;
      z-index: -1; }
      @media (min-width: 1500px) {
        .form__progress-bar::before {
          width: 95%;
          left: 3%; } }
      @media (max-width: 768px) {
        .form__progress-bar::before {
          width: 80%;
          left: 10%; } }
  .form__step {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center; }
    .form__step--number {
      border: 3px solid var(--green);
      padding: .2rem .7rem;
      border-radius: 100px;
      background-color: white;
      font-weight: 700;
      color: var(--green); }
    .form__step--name {
      font-weight: 500;
      font-size: 1.5rem;
      text-align: center; }
  .form__slider {
    width: 70%;
    padding: 2rem;
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35) 0px 5px 15px; }
    @media (max-width: 1080px) {
      .form__slider {
        width: 100%; } }
  .form__slide {
    display: none; }
  .form__field {
    position: relative; }
    .form__field::after {
      content: url("../icon/cancel.svg");
      width: 2rem;
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      right: 2%; }
    .form__field::before {
      content: url("../icon/verified.svg");
      width: 2rem;
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      right: 2%; }
  .form__input {
    background-color: var(--lightGrey);
    border: none;
    padding: 1rem;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: .5rem;
    margin-top: 2rem; }
    .form__input:valid {
      border-bottom: 2px solid var(--green) !important; }
    .form__input:not(.form__input:placeholder-shown) {
      border-bottom: 2px solid var(--orange); }
    .form__input:placeholder-shown + .form__label {
      display: none; }
  .form__label {
    position: absolute;
    top: .5rem;
    left: 0;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    font-weight: 600;
    margin-left: 1rem;
    color: var(--lightBlue); }
  .form__exclude .form__label {
    display: none; }
  .form__exclude .form__input:valid + .form__label {
    display: block; }
  .form__grid-container3 {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    gap: 0rem 2rem; }
    @media (max-width: 1000px) {
      .form__grid-container3 {
        grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr); } }
    @media (max-width: 768px) {
      .form__grid-container3 {
        grid-template-columns: 1fr; } }
  .form__grid-container2 {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    gap: 0rem 2rem; }
    @media (max-width: 768px) {
      .form__grid-container2 {
        grid-template-columns: 1fr; } }
  .form__button-contain {
    float: right;
    margin: 3rem 0rem 2rem; }
  .form__btn {
    background-color: var(--orange);
    color: white;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    padding: .8rem 2rem;
    border-radius: .5rem;
    font-size: 2rem;
    font-weight: 500;
    margin-right: 3rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow: rgba(50, 50, 93, 0.25) 0px 6px 12px -2px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 0px 3px 7px -3px; }
    .form__btn:hover {
      transform: translateY(1px); }

.icons {
  background-color: yellow; }
```

```html
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@100;200;300;400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />


  <h1 class="heading">Form SAS</h1>
  <h2 class="secondary-heading">Personal Data Sheet</h2>

  <div class="form-container">
    <form action="" class="form">
      <!-- ****** PROGRESS BAR ***** -->
      <div class="form__progress-bar">
        <div class="form__step">
          <div class="form__step--number">1</div>
          <div class="form__step--name">General Info</div>
        </div>
        <div class="form__step">
          <div class="form__step--number">2</div>
          <div class="form__step--name">Contact Info</div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- ***** SLIDER ***** -->
      <div class="form__slider">
      
      
          <div class="form__slide">
          <div class="form__title">General Information</div>
  <div class="form__field">
          <input type="text" name="firstname" class="form__input" placeholder="first Name" required />
           <label for="firstname" class="form__label">First Name</label>
           </div>           
        </div>
        
                  <div class="form__slide">
          <div class="form__title">General Information</div>
  <div class="form__field">
          <input type="text" name="fullname" class="form__input" placeholder="Last Name" required />
           <label for="lastname" class="form__label">Home Country Address</label>
           </div>           
        </div>


       
       

        <!-- BUTTONS -->
        <div class="form__button-contain">
          <button class="form__btn" id="prevBtn" onclick="nextPrev(-1)">Previous</button>
          <button class="form__btn" id="nextBtn" onclick="nextPrev(1)">Next</button> 
        </div>
     </div>
    </form>
  </div>
```

**I want to add another class in the same script that works like this class**

```
('.form__input')
```

I want them to work together without conflict.
Because I want this class in a different style, But with the same  script properties work

Comment: You haven't actually explained the problem. Why do you need this other class? What will having it achieve?

Comment: @DBS Because I want this class in a different style, but with the same work, only in the script.

Comment: in your validateForm method you can pass a parameter. const `validateForm = (formClass) = {...}` and then call it with the class name as `validateForm(".form__input")`

Comment: @AmirSaleem  i tried but i could not handle it. would you mind to write it as i can see it will be easy to catch it –

Comment: added an answer, check.

Comment: @AmirSaleem i add the full codes above in first post so please correct and let me show them , Remember . try to change any class inside input filed and put it required too , will never stay and will lead you to next step , i want to change class with new style for input and too if filed required never leave the step till fill it , hope you understand me

Answer (score 0):

You can use a parameter in place of class name, like this:

```js
const validateForm = (formClass) => {
  const childInput = slide[currentSlide].querySelectorAll(formClass);
  const arrayInput = Array.prototype.slice.call(childInput);
  let valid = true;
  arrayInput.map((input) => {
      valid = input.checkValidity();
  });
  return valid;
}

// somewhere in your code
validateForm(".form__input");
validateForm(".form__input_2");
```

Comment: what about this line showSlide(currentSlide); 

console.log(slide[0].querySelectorAll('.form__input')); will i remove it or what? excuse me i am still newbie

Comment: console.log does nothing but prints the value to console. You can remove it.

Comment: I figured out what my problem is! The problem is when I change the class to a class other than ('.form__input'); When I press the Next button, it takes me directly to the next, whether the field is required or not. Reverse when I type the class ('.form__input'); I am not allowed to move to the next if the field is required and it stays on the same page. Can you help

Comment: Your validateForm method should have the updated class. You need to pass your current form class to `nextPrev` method so that it will verify the current form only

Comment: Wait, you seem pretty good at dealing with this stuff. If I did not bother you, I can put the HTML code, style and script, and you can modify it until I see everything complete and clear

Comment: you can try, I can help you out if that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you have a progress bar that works using your script and these CSS classes : .form__slide, .form__step--number and .form__input.

You seem to use it with some query selectors based on the class.

This will be a problem if in your html you add a second form with the same classes because if you validate one form it will activate both of them.

One solution would be to define other CSS classes with the same properties but another name. It would be ugly since CSS does not have inheritance, and if the classes are not defined in a CSS file that you wrote, you will have troubles to copy paste them.

Another solution would be to use a form identifier and make your queries based on that id. It would allow you to use the same CSS classes and for your form not to be in conflict.

This way you would first select the form with the corresponding id and then apply the query selector for the CSS class on the form node returned by the first query.

Comment: @bwadall I figured out what my problem is! The problem is when I change the class to a class other than ('.form__input'); When I press the Next button, it takes me directly to the next, whether the field is required or not. Reverse when I type the class ('.form__input'); I am not allowed to move to the next if the field is required and it stays on the same page please help me.